# How can I write stdout to each text file?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to perform parallel processing using the code below;

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=x) as executor:
    result = executor.map(function, argslist)
```

and

```
def function(argslist):
    variable_1 = argstlist[0]
    variable_2 = argstlist[1]
    variable_3 = argstlist[2]
    
    sys.stdout = open(variable_1+".out", "a")
    
    (do something including prints)
```

It actually performs parallel processing as it is expected, but the output for stdout is written in one of the textfile I created altogether, although I expected stdout will be written in separate text files.
How could I solve this problem?

Comment: All threads in a process share one stdout. You can use real multiprocessing or set the "file" parameter when calling "print". Or you write your own "print" function which takes the target file from a thread local storage.

Comment: Thank you for you comment, what do you mean by real multiprocessing? Can it be realized by a python module?

Comment: The module (part of standard library) has the name "multiprocessing". There is also a "ProcessPoolExecutor" in "concurrent.futures".

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand your code but it seems that `sys.stdout` is changed only one time.

1. Maybe there should be different output files because `variable_1` has to be different, in this case, verify it
2. If it should be written in another file according the nature of what is written, you may write a subclass of `FileIO` and change its `.write()` method in order to change the file it writes towards according to what should have been in `sys.stdout`

Hoping it hasn't brought more confusion

Comment: Thank you for you answer. What I tried to do is to perform the function for list of different value of variables so variable1 should be different for each element of argslist, but I will try to understand what you have written in the second column ..